# How can I have an InkScape project exported to PDF or SVG with links still attached in the output (I am on Linux)?

Tags: linux, pdf, inkscape, svg

I have pretty big SVG in InkScape (3000px by 2000px). I want to put links to some objects in the SVG.

1. I have tried to look for PDF editor that can annotate with link in Linux. There are none (tried Okular, but it cannot annotate link).
2. I have tried to "Create Link" in InkScape, then print it to PDF. But, then my InkScape always freeze.

What are my options?

Comment: What type of links? Web URLs like https:// or internal links that point to another page in the document?

Comment: Web links! I made a CV/Portfolio with InkScape, I have some links that point out to my YouTube, various web based project in the cloud, ....

Comment: Ok, I think Sejda's PDF editor can help you. I've added more information in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Sejda's [PDF Editor](https://www.sejda.com/pdf-editor) to add web links to your PDF document.

1. Open https://www.sejda.com/pdf-editor in your browser
2. Drag and drop your PDF file to the web page
3. Click on the Link tool in the top menu
4. Select the area you want to add the link to
5. Type the web address URL in the context menu that appears

[image: How to add a link to a PDF document using Sejda PDF editor]

There's a free limit of 3 saves per hour and files smaller than 50Mb or 200 pages. If you reach these limits you'll be asked to upgrade and support the service.

If you'd rather not use an online service then there's also [Sejda Desktop](https://www.sejda.com/desktop), where files are processed locally on your computer (Windows, Mac and Linux compatible).

I'm one of the (open source) developers working on Sejda PDF. Hope this helps!

Comment: Although I want it to be free, but props for you for having weekly subscription option! I feel like, I have paid some web services for months that I only used for couple days.